# How to override Android keyboard

Tags: android

How we can override the Android keyboard in all activities on Android?

I am using it like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
             customizeDialog = mObj.new CustomizeDialog(con);
             customizeDialog.show();
        }           
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: override in ALL activities, or just the activities of your program? Also, what do you mean by "override"?

Comment: i am working on app in that app i have to override  any key in android keyboard if that key is press then my dialog box open for all activity in android mobile @nandeesh

Comment: @StealthRabbi : Override in all Activities in android  mobile and override means change the functionality of that key

Comment: @NikhilLamba: Your question is too vague to answer. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AndroDev : i am working on app in that app i have to override any key in android keyboard if that key is press then my dialog box open for all activity in android mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note following points:

- With code you posted above, you cannot handle all the keys like Home Key.
- This method will work for only one activity which is visible and not for all the activities of your application where you are trying to show dialog.
- If you want to listen to keypress event in all activities, then you have to do something. Something like send broadcast which is a bad idea.

So its better to optimize your logic.