# Override enter and space keys on Chromeos

Tags: android, google-chrome-os

First of all, this is not a duplicate question of this: [How to override Android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394436/how-to-override-android-keyboard)

My problem is a little bit different from the above one.

I'm playing music in the background in my app and I want to play/pause it if a user press to `Enter` or `Space` keys on any fragment or activity(I have only 1 activity) with a `Chromebook's keyboard`. I already implemented this and it works just fine. But there's a catch: When the user is focused on a button (ex: open X fragment), the `Space` or `Enter` key is firing the button's click event. So I want to override this.

Here's what I've tried:

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ....
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
         BackingTrackFragment.newInstance().onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
         return true;
     }
      return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
   }
}
```

**My Fragment**

```
public class SomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements KeyboardKeyEventListener {
    ...
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // play/pause the song
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface KeyboardKeyEventListener {
    boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloading `dispatchKeyEvent` fixed the problem. It will prevent any and all the key events.

**Main Activity**

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                SomeFragment.newInstance().dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

**My Fragment**

```
public class SomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements KeyboardKeyEventListener {
    ...
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        // play/pause the song
        return true;
    }
}
```

**The Interface for Overloading**

```
public interface KeyboardKeyEventListener {
    boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event);
}
```